# Proof of the fact that $[0,2]$ is not a Jordan null set.

Tags: measure-theory

The means of Jordan null set is as following.

$A \subset \mathbb{R}^1$ is a Jordan null set

$\iff$
$\forall \epsilon >0, \ \exists U_1, U_2, \cdots , U_m (\text{each } U_i(=[a_i, b_i]) \text{ is bounded closed-interval});$

\begin{equation}
A \subset \cup_{i=1}^m U_i \text{  and } \sum_{i=1}^m (b_i-a_i) < \epsilon.
\end{equation}

Then, I have to consider whether $A:=[0,2]$ is a Jordan null set or not.
Intuitively, I think $[0,2]$ is not a Jordan null set, but I cannot prove this.

In order to prove this, I have to prepare $\exists \epsilon$ and $\forall U_1, \cdots U_m$ such that $[0,2] \subset \cup_{i=1}^m U_i \text{  and } \sum_{i=1}^m (b_i-a_i) \geqq \epsilon $.

But I don't come up with how I can prove.
Please tell me some ideas.

Comment: In fact the sum of the length of intervals in any finite covering is at least $2$. Can you prove this for a covering with two intervals?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is Jordan-null then for any $\epsilon$ there is a finite family $F=\{(c_i,d_i):i\in I\}$ of bounded $open$ intervals with $c_i<d_i$ for each $i,$  such that $A\subseteq \cup F$ and $\sum_{i\in I}(d_i-c_i)<\epsilon.$

Proof: Let $U=\{[a_i,b_i]:i\in I\}$ have $m$ members, with $m\in \Bbb N,$ and with $a_i\le b_i$ for each $i,$ such that $A\subseteq \cup U$ and $$\sum_{i\in I}(b_i-a_i)<\epsilon /2.$$ The idea is to take $c_i<a_i$ and $b_i<d_i$ where each $a_i-c_i$ and each $d_i-b_i$ is small enough that $$\sum_{i\in I} (d_i-b_i)+(a_i-c_i)<\epsilon /2$$ so that $$\sum_{i\in I}(d_i-c_i)= \sum_{i\in I}(b_i-a_i) + \sum_{i\in I} (d_i-b_i)+(a_i-c_i)<\epsilon /2 +\epsilon /2.$$ For example let $d_i-b_i=a_i-c_i=(\epsilon /42)(1/m).$

So if $A $ is Jordan-null then $A$ is Lebesgue-null.